# Position React Native alert at bottom of screen

Tags: ios, react-native, alert

React Native alert defaults to showing up at the center of the screen. I've been trying to style it so that it shows up at the bottom of the screen - with no success. Does anyone know how I would go about this? I tried `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` but it still shows up in the center.

[image: iOS Alert]

Comment: What you're looking for is [action sheets](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/action-sheets/). You can use [ActionSheetIOS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/actionsheetios) API of React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this out let me know if it helps also have designed according to the image.
Copy Paste the code and try.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Pressable,
  Modal,
  Dimensions,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [showWarning, SetshowWarning] = useState(false);
  const onPressHandler = () => {
      SetshowWarning(true);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <Modal
        visible={showWarning}
        transparent
        onRequestClose={() =>
          SetshowWarning(false)
        }
        animationType='slide'
        hardwareAccelerated
      >
        <View style={styles.centered_view}>
          <View style={styles.warning_modal}>
            <View style={styles.warning_title}>
              <Text style={{
                color: '#000000',
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight:'700',
                textAlign: 'center',
              }}>Unsaved Changes</Text>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Are you sure you want to continue?</Text>
            </View>
            <Pressable
              onPress={() => SetshowWarning(false)}
              style={styles.warning_button1}
              android_ripple={{ color: '#fff' }}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textKE}>Keep Editing</Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable
              onPress={() => SetshowWarning(false)}
              style={styles.warning_button}
              android_ripple={{ color: '#fff' }}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textDC}>Discard Changes</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Button onPress={() =>onPressHandler()} title="Text This"></Button>
      {/* Add Here full code */}
    </View >
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  
  centered_view: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#00000099',
  },
  warning_modal: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: '#eeff0f0',
    borderRadius: 20,
    top:"31%"
  },
  warning_title: {
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#eff0f0',
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderColor:'grey'
  },
  warning_body: {
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textKE: {
    marginTop:20,
    color: '#1485fe',
    fontSize: 20,
    margin: 5,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  textDC: {
    marginTop:20,
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: 20,
    margin: 5,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  warning_button1: {
    height:70,
    backgroundColor: '#efeff0',
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderColor:'grey'
  },
  warning_button: {
    height:70,
    backgroundColor: '#efeff0',
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Although this works I feel like ActionSheetsIOS from react native is the easier solution. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/actionsheetios)